# How would I derive the equations of the family of lines on a hyperbolic paraboloid?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

My textbook writes out what the equations of the two one-parameter families of lines that lie on a hyperbolic paraboloid surface are, but I am having trouble figuring out how these would have been determined.

Given a simple hyperbolic paraboloid:

$z = \frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2}$

How do I determine which family of lines lies entirely on its surface?

Comment: I believe you mean the hyperboloid of revolution of one sheet, $$ x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 1;  $$ the surface you wrote does have two individual lines when $z=0$ and $y = \pm (b/a) x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your hyperbolic paraboloid in the form
$$H:\quad z=\left({x\over a}+{y\over b}\right)\left({x\over a}-{y\over b}\right)\ .$$
For given $c\in{\mathbb R}$ consider the two planes  $$P_c:\quad {x\over a}-{y\over b}=c,\qquad\qquad 
\hat P_c:\quad z=c\left({x\over a}+{y\over b}\right)\ .$$
The line
$$g_c:=P_c\wedge \hat P_c$$
then lies in $H$.

Considering in a similar way for given $d\in{\mathbb R}$ the planes
$$Q_d:\quad {x\over a}+{y\over b}=d\qquad\qquad \hat Q_c:\quad z=d\left({x\over a}-{y\over b}\right)$$
gives you the second family of lines on $H$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For the Hyperboloid of One Sheet :

$$ \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} - \frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1$$

The two families of ruled lines are given by:

$$ x(u, v) = a(cos(u) − v sin(u)), b(sin(u) + v cos(u), cv) $$

$$x(u, v) = a(cos(u)+v sin(u)), b(sin(u)−v cos(u), −cv) $$

A note on the drawing:
The actual construction of the drawing above involves taking discrete values for the variable $v$. I believe I used forty lines from one ruling and forty from the other ruling. It is intended to look like the old-fashioned string models of ruled surfaces.  The best reference I can think of to view similar models is Hilbert and Cohn-Vossen , "Geometry and the Imagination".

Comment: On the subject of your last paragraph, here's a genuine old-timey hyperboloid of one sheet, just like ma used to make: http://www.jug.net/wt/slscp/sh1s.jpg

Comment: Wonder if what I should have written down for the Hyperboloid of one sheet shouldn't be: $$ \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} - \frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1$$

Comment: Alan, yes, as @WillJagy commented above, that minus sign should be there. (The equation you wrote is an ellipsoid.)

Comment: I'll change that, Thanks.